# Convert Tensor object from Tensorflow (1.15.0) to scalar without eval()

Tags: tensorflow, type-conversion, scalar

I'm trying to convert a Tensorflow (1.15.0) tensor to a scalar, but as it is in a loop, using the eval() function EXTREMELY slows down the program execution.

It's even more annoying that the tensor is a scalar value, not even an array.

Is it possible to go extract this value without eval() ?

I also tried to use .numpy() but I get an error (Tensor object has no attribute numpy), so it's not a valid method either.

Thank you.

Comment: You could always try `sess.run(tensor)`, however I don't think that it would be much faster than the `eval()` function. `tensor.numpy()` is available only for eager execution.

Comment: I can try sess.run() but I think it would be the same. The problem is all the overhead of run() just to return a scalar.

Comment: I'm not aware of any *faster* way to do this. One hack I could think of would be to stack these tensors into larger tensor (like you would stack scalars in an array) and evaluate the whole object once. I'd recommend switching to tf2, though, where you don't have these issues!

Comment: I can try that. Unfortunately, I'm using a library not yet compatible with tf2, so I cannot really update it.